# golang: bitwise operation on very long binary bit string representation

Tags: string, go, bit, bitwise-operators

As an exercise, in input I got 2 very big **string** containing long binary representation here a short one but could have more than 100 bits:

Example

```
11100
00011
```

With output in bitwise OR (as string)

```
11111
```

My approach was to parse each string characters and make a bitwise OR and build a new string but it is too long to process on big entry and not effective.

Then ParseInt method is restricted to a 64 bit length

```
num1, err:= strconv.ParseInt("11100", 2, 64)
num2, err:= strconv.ParseInt("00011", 2, 64)
res := num1 | num2
```

How to deal with a bitwise OR between 2 string binary representation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *could* create the resulting bitwise OR string by doing character comparisons, or you can perform arbitrary large numeric operations using [`math/big`](https://godoc.org/math/big).  Here is an example of such an operation:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "math/big"

func main() {
    num1 := "11100"
    num2 := "00011"

    var bigNum1 big.Int
    var bigNum2 big.Int
    var result big.Int

    if _, ok := bigNum1.SetString(num1, 2); !ok {
        panic("invalid num1")
    }
    if _, ok := bigNum2.SetString(num2, 2); !ok {
        panic("invalid num2")
    }
    result.Or(&bigNum1, &bigNum2)

    for i := result.BitLen() - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        fmt.Print(result.Bit(i))
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6K_nQaqKbl)

Comment: thanks, it is perfect I had looked to math/big but not enough to see this convert methods, Go documentation is not well displayed to my opinon, to much scroll

Answer (score 0):

While you could convert these to numbers to perform bitwise operations, if your only goal is to perform a single bitwise OR on the two strings, parsing the strings into numbers will be less efficient than simply iterating over the string to achieve your end result. Doing so would only make sense if you were performing lots of operations on the numbers in their binary form.

Example code for performing an OR operation on the strings below. Do note that this code assumes the strings are the same length as the examples in the question are, if they were of different lengths you would need to handle that as well.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    n1 := "1100"
    n2 := "0011"

    fmt.Printf("Input: %v | %v\n", n1, n2)

    if len(n1) != len(n2) {
        fmt.Println("Only supports strings of the same length")
        return
    }

    result := make([]byte, len(n1))

    for i := 0; i < len(n1); i++ {
        switch n1[i] {
        case '0':
            switch n2[i] {
            case '0':
                result[i] = '0'
            case '1':
                result[i] = '1'
            }
        case '1':
            switch n2[i] {
            case '0':
                result[i] = '1'
            case '1':
                result[i] = '1'
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Result: ", string(result))
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/L3o6_jYdi1

Comment: You would need to pad them out if their lengths weren't identical.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
    a :=   "01111100"
    b := "1001000110"

    var longest, len_diff int 

    if len(a) > len(b) {
        longest = len(a)
        len_diff = len(a) - len(b)
    } else {
        longest = len(b)
        len_diff = len(b) - len(a)
    }

    temp_slice := make([] byte, longest)

    var a_start, b_start int

    if len(a) > len(b) {
        for i := 0; i < len_diff; i++ {
            temp_slice[i] = a[i]
        }
        a_start = len_diff

    } else {
        for i := 0; i < len_diff; i++ {
            temp_slice[i] = b[i]
        }
        b_start = len_diff
    }

    for i := 0; i < (longest - len_diff); i++ {
        if a[a_start + i] == '1' ||  b[b_start + i] == '1' {
            temp_slice[len_diff + i] = '1'
        } else {
            temp_slice[len_diff + i] = '0'
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(string(temp_slice))
}
```

[goplayground](https://play.golang.org/p/GY5ko1nf3x)

Comment: Don't use `48` and `49` when `'0'` and `'1'` are more appropriate and readable.

Comment: Instead of mucking about with `strings.Repeat` (and the associated allocations) it would be simpler just to copy the leading bytes as-is from the longest input before switching to doing bit ops.

Comment: @DaveC, thanks for the suggestions. I think they are both good; I modified my code to reflect them.

Comment: Sorry to belabor this, but `copy(tmp[:lenDiff], a); a := a[lenDiff:]` (or b) (idiomatic Go identifier names use [mixedCaps](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#mixed-caps) rather than under_scores) would be better than a manual loop and having to remembering an offset to how much remains (i.e. by the last loop it would be nice if the `a` and `b` where now the same length with just the remaining bits and `tmp` could just be appended to to finish off).

Comment: E.g. perhaps something more like https://play.golang.org/p/V5l73KxaI2 maybe (feel free to copy or improve on that).

Comment: @DaveC, thanks for your help. I think your answer is significantly different (and better) from mine, so you probably should provide it as separate answer. Please do it is a nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: try this library:https://github.com/aristofanio/bitwiser.
you can parse large bytes arrays like bitstring. See:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/aristofanio/bitwiser"
)

func main() {
    //
    b0, _ := bitwiser.ParseFromBits("011100")
    b1, _ := bitwiser.ParseFromBits("11010011100")
    //
    println(b0.ToString()) //output: 0x1c   (len(array) = 1byte)
    println(b1.ToString()) //output: 0x069c (len(array) = 2bytes)
}
```